# Youtube-dl not letting me write to a folder that I have access to

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube-dl

IM making a Youtube downloader with `youtube-dl` and when I specify a path it says i do not have permission even though I do.

Here is the script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.constants import DISABLED
from tkinter import filedialog
import youtube_dl
import ctypes, sys
window = tk.Tk()
optionswindow = Tk()
f = False
t = True

def closeoptions():
    optionswindow.withdraw()  

def options():
    optionswindow.deiconify()

optionswindow.geometry("360x640")
optionswindow.resizable(t, t)
global canvas2
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(optionswindow, width = 360, height = 640)
canvas2.pack()     
canvas2.create_window(360, 640)

optionswindow.title("Options...")
global pathnotify
pathnotify = tk.Label(optionswindow, text="Where Shall We Save The File?")
pathnotify.place(x=25, y=5)
closebutton = tk.Button(optionswindow, text="Close", width=10, command=closeoptions)
def BrowseLocal():
    Browsed = t
    global TheEntry
    TheEntry = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Where Shall We Save The File?")
    if Browsed == t:  
        getinfo()

def getinfo():
    print(TheEntry)
BrowseButton = tk.Button(optionswindow, text="Browse...", width=40, command=BrowseLocal)
BrowseButton.place(x=25, y=25)
closebutton.place(x=5, y=610)
optionswindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeoptions)  

def click():
    messagebox.showinfo("We are now downloading this video","We are now downloading the video, please 
    wait. If you have not specified the path you would like to save the file in, the file will save 
    in your user folder")
    options = {'outtmpl': TheEntry}
    x1 = linkbox.get()
    youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(x1, download=False)
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as download:
        download.download([x1])


 optionswindow.withdraw()
 window.title("Youtube Downloader")
 window.minsize(250,50) 
 window.resizable(False, False)
 canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width = 275, height = 75)
 canvas1.pack()
 linkbox = tk.Entry (window) 
 canvas1.create_window(100, 25, window=linkbox)
 window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
 optionbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Options...", width=40, command=options)
 optionbutton.place(x=0, y=50)



 downloadbutton = tk.Button(window, compound=tk.LEFT, width=10, height=1,
      text="Download", bg='white', command=click)



 downloadbutton.place(x=170, y=12) 



 window.mainloop()
```

I make the script save the video to my documents but then it says this

```
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Naeem\\Documents'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\http.py", line 260, in download
    ctx.tmpfilename, ctx.open_mode)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\utils.py", line 2054, in sanitize_open
    stream = open(encodeFilename(filename), open_mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Naeem\\Documents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\Documents\Coding Project\Downloader\Ui\Files\UI.py", line 51, in click
    download.download([x1])
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2029, in download
    url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 796, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 803, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 835, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 869, in process_ie_result
    return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1654, in process_video_result
    self.process_info(new_info)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1936, in process_info
    success = dl(filename, info_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 1875, in dl
    return fd.download(name, info)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\common.py", line 366, in download
    return self.real_download(filename, info_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\http.py", line 352, in real_download
    return download()
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\http.py", line 265, in download
    self.report_error('unable to open for writing: %s' % str(err))
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\common.py", line 165, in report_error
    self.ydl.report_error(*args, **kargs)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Naeem\\Documents'
```

**EDIT**

I am n ow using `askdirectory()` and changing some options on youtube-dl and now it works! Thanks to @acw1668! Apparently i had to use forcefilname and other commands to make sure that it didnt overwrite the whole directory.

Comment: Do you have it already open in some other window?

Comment: Please format your errors like you have your code

Comment: I think you should use `asksaveasfilename()` instead of `askdirectory()`.

Comment: @AbhishekRai No i do not have it open. But thats not the problem, its saying a permission error?

Comment: @WBM Sorry ill change that

Comment: @acw1668 Some other program might be using the directory..That's what I meant.

Comment: If directory name is used and youtube_dl uses the directory name as the output file, then will raise permission error because you cannot overwrite a directory.

Comment: @AbhishekRai I know what you mean, there is no program using it though. I checked task manager in detail and n ot even background apps or services were using it

Comment: @acw1668 im not telling it to overwrite. I am appending data

Comment: If you want to use `askdirectory()` to specify the directory to hold the downloaded video, use `options = {"outtmpl": f"{TheEntry}/%(title)s", "strictfilenames": True}` inside `click()`.  The the output filename of the video will be its *title* inside the selected directory.

Comment: thanks that really helped! Now it works better :)